# I have a custom SVG board I want to replace the chess.svg.board with

Tags: chessboards

I made my own custom SVG chess board, and I would like to replace the default chessboard in chess.svg.board with the custom chess board I have. The issue is that I have a ton of paths in the svg. Is there a way to replace the chess.svg.board with my own custom SVG board? and is there a way to get rid of the majority of the paths without changing the look of the board.

The board I am trying to use is this one:[image]